# Display android listview based upon listview selection

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have a listview say in this instance has the values:

UK,
USA,
FRANCE

These values are pulled from a static array held within my string.xml file. Additionally, within the string.xml is 3 arrays each referring to UK, USA and FRANCE & basically I want to load these arrays into a new listview depending on the users onclick event.

Essentially I dont know how to pass the users selection to the new listview and populate accordingly. I know the process incorporates the use of an intent but being an android newbie I am not exactly sure how!

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

You have a few options:

1) Use the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) from the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

2) Create a new Bundle

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.extras.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

3) Use the [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) shortcut method of the Intent

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
mIntent.putExtra(key, value);
```

**New Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this getter is just for example purpose, can differ
if (myIntent !=null && myIntent.getExtras()!=null)
     String value = myIntent.getExtras().getString(key);
}
```

***NOTE:*** Bundles have "get" and "put" methods for all the primitive types, Parcelables, and Serializables. I just used Strings for demonstrational purposes.